# Scala + Slick how to map json to the table column with datatype as blob

Tags: json, scala, slick

I need to map json values to the table using slick and store whole json as a blob in the same table as well.

```
def createJob(jobs: JobEntity): Future[Option[Long]] =
db.run(job returning job.map((_.id)) += jobs)
```

My Json contains values like

```
id(long),name(string), type(string)
```

while the table I am trying to map has columns

```
id(long),name(string), type(string),json_data(blob)
```

I have JobEntity class as

```
case class JobEntity(id: Option[Long] = None, name: String, type: String) {

require(!jobname.isEmpty, "jobname.empty")

}
```

How do I map the json to the json_data column?

Answer (score 0):

Slick supports the following LOB types: `java.sql.Blob, java.sql.Clob, Array[Byte]` (see the [documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/schemas.html))

Therefore you want to use one of these types. Your table definition could look like this:

```
  case class Job(id: Option[Long] = None, name: String, `type`: String, json_data: java.sql.Blob)

  class Jobs(tag: Tag) extends Table[Job](tag, "jobs") {
    def id = column[Option[Long]]("id")
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def `type` = column[String]("type")
    def json_data = column[java.sql.Blob]("json_data")
    def * = (id, name, `type`, json_data) <> (Job.tupled, Job.unapply)
  }
```