# What datatype to use in Slick Table definiton for json?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, slick

A table in my database has a column with the type json. I am wondering, which data type should I use when I define the table in Slick? 
Currently, for the specific column I use Blob since I found it suggested  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43784131/scala-slick-how-to-map-json-to-the-table-column-with-datatype-as-blob). 
I'm interested to know if it is possible to use the json library class provided Play framework (play.libs.json)? If so, how? Do I need implicit mappers?

Answer (score 1):

Slick provides [custom data type mapper](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/v3.2.1/doc/code/LiftedEmbedding.scala#L491-L502) which are not supported by Slick.
In my case: Saving Json as string into database and in code using as JValue(I am using [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s)):

```
object JsonMapper{
   import driver.api._

   implicit val jsonMapper = MappedColumnType.base[JValue, String](
      { json => write(framesType) /* json writer */ }, 
      { str =>parse(str)  /*json parser */ }
     )
  }

 import JsonMapper._

  case class Info(id:Int, json:JValue)
  class DBTable(tag:Tag) extends Table[Info](tag, "info"){
    val id = column[Int]("id")
    val json = column[JValue]("json")
    def * = (id ,json) <> (Info.tupled, Info.unapply)
  }
```

I am not sure this will work for your case. But this is a way to map any custom data type in Slick.